# Object Rotation when camera following

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to set an objection rotation to `Math.PI / 180 * 90`, however, the problem is that when I add the camera to my object by `object.add(camera)`, I cannot modify any of my objects rotations anymore. When I take off the camera from the object, it is working fine. I'm using `OrbitContrls`. What I'm basically trying to do is to switch the rotation axis of the orbit controls, which I do through the `.rotation.x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out what I could do is modify the up for the camera and it will sort things out. I did:

```
camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
```

and my problems were solved.